# ASP.NET MVC5 - Error al dar más de un clic para logearme - The provided anti-forgery token was meant for a different claims-based user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

buen día he buscado para solucionar este error. Me percaté que al dar doble clic en el botón de Log In, me tira este error, creo entender que es porque se envian dos solicitudes de inicio de sesión al mismo tiempo. Espero puedan ayudarme. 
La siguiente imágen muestra el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el código que yo tengo para logearme, agrege en el POST DE Login un try catch para una excepcción HttpAntiForgeryException  pero no me funciona. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a solucionar este error y explicarmelo.

> ```
>   // GET: /Account/Login
>     [AllowAnonymous]
>     public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
>     {
>         ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
>         return View();
>     }
> ```

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {           
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

            if( user != null)
            {
                IdentityUserRole role;
                if (user.Roles.Count() > 0 && user.Roles != null)
                {
                    role = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault();
                    getRoleUser = role;

                    //Search if the user is active, that the data of column Logical Delete be equals that 0
                    bool userActive = GetUserIsActive(role.UserId,role.RoleId);
                    if (userActive == false)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.");
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
            }

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpAntiForgeryException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: quieres una solución rápida: deshabilita el botón mediante javascript luego de darle click.

Comment: Quita el decorador [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] y ya no tendrás problemas. No obstante es una opción de seguridad importante, para saber cual es el error que está causando este problema muestra el código de tu vista.

Comment: @fredyfx lo que agrege en la vista fue código javascript para evitar que se enviara doble vez la petición al servidor, y así poder solucionar el problema.

Comment: @AlfredoManuelCanReséndiz si pense en retirar de primero el [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] pero después recorde como lo dijiste brinda seguridad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la solución de mi respuesta, agregue una validación del lado del cliente.
Agrege en el Html.BeginForm en el parámetro de los atributos

> html, @submit = "return checkSubmit();"

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, 
     FormMethod.Post,new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", 
     @onsubmit = "return checkSubmit();" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                }
            </div>
```

En el código js podemos ver que al enviar la solicitud por primera vez la variable sent tomara valor "true" y si el cliente vuelve a enviar otra petición al servidor antes de enviarse se ejecuta el código js y como sent es "true" por lo tanto regresa
un false y la petición ya no se vuelve a enviar. 
El código js es el siguiente

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        sent = false;
        function checkSubmit() {
            if (!sent) {
                sent = true;
                return true;
            } else {
                //alert("Request is Processing");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Se que necesito para mayor seguridad agregar también validación del lado del servidor 
y así tener una respuesta más completa.
Este código no es mio el de js, pero no recuerdo de que blog lo obtuve. Por lo tanto no es de mi autoría pero es una buena solución. 
Aunque el error podría presentarse en otra ocación, por ejemplo si el usuario abre dos tabs y en una cierra sesión y trata de iniciar sesión, se mostrará el mismo error debido que la otra tab mantiene aun la sesión.
Y como se mencionaba en un comentario, el atributo

> [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

le dice al usuario practicamente que no pueden dos personas iniciar sesión, solo puede entrar una.

Answer (score 0):

El error puede significar:

- Que el navegador notó que el usuario que intenta iniciar sesión es
  diferente al usuario que se identificó previamente para este
  navegador.
- Esto puede suceder si la ventana del navegador se cierra
  inesperadamente. Hay diferentes inicios de sesión en diferentes
  pestañas del navegador o, simplemente, el sistema no terminó de
  cerrar sesión y el token de seguridad no se ha eliminado.

algunas soluciones pueden ser no guardar cache, colocando esta linea antes del metodo login:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

o realizando la siguiente validación;

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
  Session.Abandon(); //Destruir sessión
  if (AuthenticationManager.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
  ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
  return View();
}
```